# How to design a database for subcategories with different field sets?

Tags: database, database-design

For a school project, I am designing a system to document different types of architectural violations for disabled people (Sorry for my language if I am being rude, I am not English speaker).

There are many different categories and subcategories of violations, and each subcategory of violation has different set of fields. The form for adding violations will be dynamic, according to the subcategory, user will face different set of fields. A field may be binary or integer. Some of the violations may have multiple fields.

My question is how should I design such a system's database?

The idea that I had so far is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBZTK.png)

What do you think about this design? This is the first time I implement such a system, so I have no idea about how will it work.

Comment: I am marking it as off-topic.  Other sites here are a better fit for algorithm / code preview.

Comment: Perhaps better suited for [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/?tags=database-design). Btw, have a look at the [WordPress database model](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) for inspiration - it has some good (and some bad) ideas.

Comment: When you write about "different set of field" what do you mean? Different values of fields or real different fields? I explain. In first case you have table with two fields: integer I, and binary B. And user could enter different values in that table, but fields stay the same. In second case you have table with many fields: I1, I2, ..., In; B1, B2, ..., Bm. And user enter values in predefined set fields. Which case is yourth?

Comment: Real different fields. For instance a ramp violation has a slope field. However, a grid violation will have grid gap and grid orientation (binary) fields. User will be able to provide any value.

Comment: Perhaps do some research on an EAV (Entity Attribute Value) design. This is generally frowned upon but doing some research will give you some ideas of its good and bad points.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how Wordpress is designed, with many fewer tables than other cmses - the posts table only has basic fields, while the variations on data needed for many different post-types are handled in wp-postmeta - which has four fields - post id, meta name and meta value (plus order, which is seldom needed).